# Is there a Java interface that only have `get` `set` methods?

Tags: java

The `get`, `set` methods refer to array-like APIs, not `getter`s or `setter`s.

I've googled "java interface get set" and didn't get useful results -- it gives me information like `getter`s or `setter`s.

I've implemented a boolean array using bit compression, and I want know if there's an interface that only have `get(int)` and `set(int, boolean)`.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the interface you need?

Comment: Java already has a `BitSet` class for managing sets of booleans.  Do you need to implement your own?  As to a "standard" interface there is none, but you can certainly make your own.

Comment: @StefanReich I just want to know if there's a general-purpose one.

Comment: @JimGarrison Ooops. Thank you. Then I don't have to implement one myself :)

Comment: Ah, so that's what he means with "bit compression" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there probably isn't.

My implementation is exactly the same as `java.util.BitSet`, which only implements `Serializable` and `Cloneable`.
This means there isn't such interface in the standard library.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all. There may or may not be such an interface in the JDK, but `BitSet` isn't proof that it doesn't exist. It's hard to see why you want such a thing in the first place.

Comment: @EJP I think OP just wants to summarize by writing "*this means*". I don't think that it was meant to be the follow-up of the `BitSet` thing. A bit unlucky though if that's the case.

Comment: @EJP Since you guys told me the existense of `BitSet`, I wish I can detete this post..

Comment: Actually you can delete the question and/or the answer, you're the mighty OP. There should be a link somewhere around. But if you think that the question might help other users you might reconsider your decision.

Comment: Eh.. Ok I'll just leave it here. Thanks for all of your help.